# Android has only 15 volume positions, how can I adjust it more precisely using java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to make a very small app that can precisely modify the phones volume, I got it working but the problem is that Android only has 15 volume positions and I want to be able to set volumes like 95, 96, 97, etc.

What could be a way I can do this? I'm using AudioManager to tweak the audio.

Thanks

```
Button plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)-1,0);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)+1,0);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    });
```

Comment: [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46979/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-volume-levels) post may help you

Answer (score 1):

Basically you **cant** do that as a programmer and that's a series of steps the user has to do.

Check my comment.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out too, but there is an app that can override the 15 volume levels (precise volume) and I was wondering how that was possible. I tried searching the source code but there's too many files and I can't find anything useful.

Comment: As you are a new user ill inform you that there is a checkmark to the left side of the answer to mark the answer as the answer to your question. if one of the answers you have got helped you consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: From my experince, you cant do that.